# Can I change the public key of the root certificate of fiddler?

Tags: ssl, fiddler

An program I want to capture HTTPS traffic from uses Mozilla's pem file with SSL certificates that should be trusted, I want fiddler to mimic one of these certificates so I can go through the SSL pinning. I don't know how and if this is possible so if anyone can help I'd appreciate it!

Comment: If the pinning is correctly implemented (e.g. pinning based on the certificate hash) it is next to impossible to bypass the pinning. In general I would recommend to decompile the app that uses pinning and check how they do it. If it is done correctly you can only modify the app and disable the pinning.

Comment: Its based on the public key so practically getting myself an trusted ssl certificate should work. I have one now bt Fiddler is having a hard time sing another certificate as the root